# UTC DateTime Serialization in WCF Services

Tags: wcf, datetime, serialization, soap, utc

I have to use a customer web service which contains some DateTime. They send me a SOAP example and the expected serialization format is "2016-08-06T13:40:00Z". Problem is when I serialize my DateTime then the format is "2016-08-06T13:40:00" and therefore I get an exception from the WebService. I read in some articles that I have to specify the DateTime Kind to UTC. I did it but without success. Format is still "2016-08-06T13:40:00". Any idea how to handle this case?

Comment: I would expect a UTC DateTime to be serialized with the Z suffix.  Show the code where you are specifying DateTimeKind = UTC without success.

Comment: DateTime.SpecifyKind(flightStatusNotificationViewModel.LegInformationModel1.ScheduledDeparture.Value, DateTimeKind.Utc);

Just before sending the date to the service, I display the date with the universal format to check and here the Z is displayed.. 
Debug.WriteLine(flightTriggerRequest.FlightInformation.FlightLegs[0].FSFlightDeparture.Estimated.Value.ToString("u"));

Comment: You don't appear to be assigning the result of the DateTime.SpecifyKind method back to the field you're serializing.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot. I though this mehod would change the type on the flight but actually creates an new instance.